# Simplest way to dismiss Bootstrap alerts when the containing modal is dismissed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am dynamically showing alerts inside of modals, using Bootstrap 3. I would like the alerts to be dismissed if the modal gets dismissed. So if I show an error alert, the user dismisses the modal to fix their mistake, and then brings the modal back up, the error alert won't be there when the modal returns.

I know I can manually set this up this way:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.alert', $(this)).alert('close');
});
```

But I want to know if there's a simpler way, perhaps with data- attributes, to have a modal close all alerts inside of it when hidden. Instead of just planting that strip of code on any page that uses a modal.

Here is a typical modal with an alert in it:

```
<div id="modalNew" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Thing</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form> ... </form>
                <div class="alertbox">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                       <strong>Error!</strong> You did it wrong.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SubmitForm()">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, Bootstrap doesn't allow multiple `data-dismiss` values. Even if you try setting the cancel button's `data-dismiss` value to `alert`, it hides the modal footer instead for some reason.

I would say using your couple of jQuery lines on each page is the only option outside of some kind of crazy hack.